# C++ Thread safe queue shutdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm using this class for producer-consumer setup in C++:

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

template <typename T> class SafeQueue
{
public:
    SafeQueue() :
    _shutdown(false)
    {

    }

    void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
        bool was_empty = _queue.empty();
        _queue.push(std::move(item));
        lock.unlock();

        if (was_empty)
            _condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    bool Dequeue(T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);

        while (!_shutdown && _queue.empty())
            _condition_variable.wait(lock);

        if(!_shutdown)
        {
            item = std::move(_queue.front());
            _queue.pop();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
        return _queue.empty();
    }

    void Shutdown()
    {
        _shutdown = true;
        _condition_variable.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::mutex _queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condition_variable;
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    std::atomic<bool> _shutdown;
};
```

And I use it like this:

```
class Producer
{
public:
    Producer() :
        _running(true),
        _t(std::bind(&Producer::ProduceThread, this))
    { }

    ~Producer()
    {
        _running = false;
        _incoming_packets.Shutdown();
        _t.join();
    }

    SafeQueue<Packet> _incoming_packets;

private:
    void ProduceThread()
    {
        while(_running)
        {
            Packet p = GetNewPacket();
            _incoming_packets.Enqueue(p);
        }
    }

    std::atomic<bool> _running;
    std::thread _t;
}

class Consumer
{
    Consumer(Producer* producer) :
        _producer(producer),
        _t(std::bind(&Consumer::WorkerThread, this))
    { }

    ~Consumer()
    {
        _t.join();
    }

private:
    void WorkerThread()
    {
        Packet p;

        while(producer->_incoming_packets.Dequeue(p))
            ProcessPacket(p);
    }

    std::thread _t;
    Producer* _producer;
}
```

This works *most* of the time. But once in a while when I delete the producer (and causing it's deconstructor to call `SafeQueue::Shutdown`, the `_t.join()` blocks forever.

My guess is the that the problem is here (in `SafeQueue::Dequeue`):

```
while (!_shutdown && _queue.empty())
        _condition_variable.wait(lock);
```

`SafeQueue::Shutdown` from thread #1 gets called while thread #2 finished checking **_shutdown** but before it executed `_condition_variable.wait(lock)`, so it "misses" the `notify_all()`. Can this happen?

If that's the problem, what's the best way to solve it?

Comment: Do you turn on your warnings at the maximum level? You have a subtle bug in your Consumer class. The Order of your data members and the order which you intend to initialize them in your constructor conflicts.... Check it. The thread will be created before `_producer` is assigned

Comment: Again you are using condition variable wrongly... Its not supposed to be in a while loop like that. It has an overload that allows such testing

Comment: @WhiZTiM I know it has an overload like this, but it's equivalent to a while loop: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I'm not fully understand how this causes a livelock, maybe I'm missing something obvious here... *std::condition_variable::wait:* `Atomically releases lock, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on *this. The thread will be unblocked when notify_all() or notify_one() is executed. It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits.` (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

Comment: Can this happen? Yes.  The notify_all doesn't guarantee a thread context switch.  The consumer can be in the wait call, and ~Producer will destroy the queue.  Consumer's pointer to the producer is now invalid.  The memory previously occupied by the queue is invalid.  How the wait code will behave when the consumer thread is activated is now undefined.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to make 'shutdown' a special entry in the queue.  ie push a "shutdown" message onto the queue.  This can make the loop/wait simpler, and also means nothing in the queue gets left behind (which may or may not be the behaviour you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the SafeQueue object is owned by the producer, deleting the producer causes a race condition between the consumer being notified and the SafeQueue being deleted out from under it when ~Producer completes.

I suggest having the shared resource being owned by neither the producer nor consumer, but passed as a reference to the constructor of each.

Change the Producer and Consumer constructors;

```
Producer( SafeQueue<Packet> & queue ) :
    _running(false), _incoming_packets(queue) {}


Consumer( SafeQueue<Packet> & queue ) :
    _running(false), _incoming_packets(queue) {}
```

Use your instances this way;

```
SafeQueue<Packet> queue;
Producer producer(queue);  
Consumer consumer(queue);

...do stuff...

queue.shutdown();
```

This also resolves a poor design issue you have in the Consumer class being so tightly coupled to the Producer class.

Also, it's probably a bad idea to kill and join threads in a destructor, as you do for ~Producer. Better to add a Shutdown() method to each thread class, and call them explicitly;

```
producer.shutdown();
consumer.shutdown();
queue.shutdown();
```

Shutdown order doesn't really matter, unless you are concerned about losing unprocessed packets that are still in the queue when you stop the consumer.

Comment: Why is it a bad design to join threads in the deconstructor? Isn't it conflicting with RAII?

Comment: @UnTraDe, Creating and destroying would be RAII, starting and stopping is program control.  But, further, `join` can throw exceptions, which means proper handling requires even more logic in a destructor, which definitely conflicts with RAII.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SafeQueue::Dequeue`, you are probably using `std::condition_variable` the wrong way... Change this:

```
bool Dequeue(T& item)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);

    while (!_shutdown && _queue.empty())
        _condition_variable.wait(lock);
    if(!_shutdown)
    {
        item = std::move(_queue.front());
        _queue.pop();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

to

```
bool Dequeue(T& item)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
   _condition_variable.wait(lock, []{ return _shutdown || !_queue.empty() });
    if(!_shutdown)
    {
        item = std::move(_queue.front());
        _queue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Secondly, the order of initialization of the data members in `Consumer` isn't right with regards to its constructor

```
class Consumer
{
    Consumer(Producer* producer) :
        _producer(producer),
        _t(std::bind(&Consumer::WorkerThread, this))
    { }
    ......
    // _t will be constructed first, regardless of your constructor initializer list
    // Meaning, the thread can even start running using an unintialized _producer
    std::thread _t;      
    Producer* _producer;
}
```

It should be reordered to:

```
class Consumer
{
    Consumer(Producer* producer) :
        _producer(producer),
        _t(std::bind(&Consumer::WorkerThread, this))
    { }
    ......
    Producer* _producer;
    std::thread _t;      
}
```

Another part of your problem is covered by [CAB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513180/1621391)

Comment: The original `while (!pred) condvar.wait(lock);` code is correct and your change is wrong, because when passing a predicate, the wait stops when the predicate is true, so it should be `_shutdown || !_queue.empty()`